# Making sure asynchronous calls happen in order in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a frontend in Angular and backend in Rails.
In Angular side, I send many http requests and sometimes those requests need to happen in order to make sure the app works in a proper way.

Based on my research, people use promises for this reason. Is this true? Does promise ensure that one happens after when previous action is fully done and response is back?

Let's look at my exmaple.

I have a promise which returns application object. If it does not exist in localStorage, my app fetches from the remote server.

```
    ApplicationModule.get = function () {

            if (!localStorage.application) {
                return Restangular.all('session').one('user').get().then(function (response) {
                    application = {
                            "id": response.current_application_id,
                            "user_id": response.id,
                            "_type": response.current_type
                        }
                    localStorage.setItem("application", JSON.stringify(application));
                    return application
                });
            } else {
                return $q.resolve(JSON.parse(localStorage.application));
            }
    }

    return ApplicationModule;
}]);
```

In my other controller, I utilize function in following way. I basically need to get response back from `ApplicationModule.get()` and use that as a param in next function `somefunction`.

```
        ApplicationModule.get().then(function (response) {
           somefunction(response);
        })
```

What I'm curious is that if I use promise, does `somefunction()`always gets called after `return Restangular.all('session').one('user').get().then(function (response)` is done in ApplicationModule.get()?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery's `$.ajax` , it already returns a Promise which you can use its `then` method.

Nonetheless Promises are not for ordering things but they are for asynchronous computations, it's simply a coincidence that AJAX is asynchronous(notice the "A") and so it's logical for `$.ajax` to return a Promise.

They can be chained so that when the first succeeds its result get passed to the second and so on but that's not their main use.

Their main use is asynchronous computing and the `then` method exists because sometimes you need to do another asynchronous operation with the result of the first.

When you need to order synchronous computations promises shouldn't be used, in your usecase though it's the perfect idea.

Comment: So, promises is used for the purpose of multiple asynchronous computing if there is anything to do with previous result right? And I'm doing it in a right way right?

Comment: yes you're doing the right thing considered ajax is asynchronous, promises can be used for one computation too though